# Rename UITextView Return key

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm trying to find a way how to rename the Return Key in a textView. I am sure it is somehow possible despite the fact that some claim it cannot be done.

I already have the return key process another action rather then adding a line. And I know there is a list of other names that can be used to change the title of the return key, but I would like to put in my own text. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Set the `returnKeyType` property. That's your only option. No arbitrary label supported unless you create your own custom keyboard.

Comment: what about adding something like UIImageView on top of the keyboard? Except I would need to know how to get something to be displayed above the keyboard

Comment: Any attempt to modify or overlay an existing keyboard is a waste of effort and will likely break on the next iOS update. What label do you want?

Comment: look at  <UIKeyInput, UITextInputTraits> protocols, this should allow you to trap any key .... but as @rmaddy states, if you want to rename the "key label" you'll need to create your own custom keyboard

Comment: I want to rename it to "Run"

Comment: @MDB983 Thanks, it probably is best to just keep it simple. unfortunately, it's a shame that the return key would be confusing to the user.

Comment: Just to add to the above comments, if you try to hack your way around this, your app may get rejected. So best bet is to go with standard user conventions.

Comment: Why not use "Go"? That should be close enough to "Run".

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have already stated, you can't change the text of the return key on the keyboard. If you'd like to add a "run" button in a way that's relatively standard I would recommending setting the `inputAccessoryView`property to be a `UIToolBar` with a "run" button in it. Something like this, but with "run" instead of "done":

[image: Input accessory view]